# Oшибка при переходе с http на https на nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

`localhost` на `http` работает корректно. Но нужно перейти на `https`. 
В конфигурационном файле я вставила эти строки, после чего открывается `homе page` с `https`, но не корректно (там все смешанo), и после нажатии на ссылку открывается страницы с `http`?

---

```
server { 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    root /path/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name mysite.com mysite.com;

    ssl on; 
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

Comment: А можно увидеть более полный конфиг?

Comment: после строки try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; идет rewrite ruls, я использовала convert htaaccess to nginx и вставила тут. и все

Comment: ссылки на странице абсолютные или относительные?

Comment: ссылки относительные

Comment: а в файле `/index.php` — чистый html, или его надо интерпретировать программой *php*? если второе, то секция, выполняющая интерпретацию, у вас имеется внутри приведённой секции `server`?

Comment: либо абсолютные ссылки с указанием схемы "http", либо мы видим не весь конфиг, либо переадресацией занимается бекенд. что происходит если в адресной строке написать полный адрес любой другой страницы с https? какие заголовки шлёт сервер?

Comment: alexander barakin это мой index.php <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 define("is_file_included?", 1);
 include 'define.php';
 include 'includes.php';
?>

Comment: он имел ввиду секцию в конфиге nginx в его ssl-ной части

Comment: error_page 404 /404.html;
 location = /50x.html {
  root /path/;
 } 
 location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
 fastcgi_keep_conn on;
 try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params; } }

Comment: это было продолжение моего config файла

Comment: А может это поможет Вам. Когда я делаю "inspect element" то в <head> </head> все ссылки вот таком виде( с http://). <script src = http:// http://mysite.com/path/.js> </script>..... , но  в адресной строке все эти ссылки с http, открывается и с https.

Comment: Narine, вы понимаете разницу между абсолютной и относительной ссылкой?

Comment: после Вашего вопроса я гуглила :)

Comment: абсолютные ссылки только в в <head> а в основном нет ссылки ведут отсчет от корня сайта.

Comment: удивительно. тогда прочитайте [это](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki) и используйте то, что там называется "Ссылки относительно корня сайта".

Comment: если ссылки от корня то проблем не должно быть или проблема не в настройках nginx

Comment: вот это и я прочитала. Спасибо